# Excel for Mac - unable to create my own macros

Tags: macros, microsoft-excel-2011, office-for-mac

I have a macro (made for Excel - Windows), which url encode strings - i.e. space becomes %20.
When I open the *.xlsm on a Mac with Excel installed(Office for Mac 2011), it does not work.
No errors - nothing!!
I found this from googling - http://blog.mclaughlinsoftware.com/2010/11/04/excel-2011-without-udfs/
I have tried re-installing as described in the link above with no success. I can not even get the small "tests" to work as described.

```
Function hello()
  hello = "Hello World!"
End Function

Function hellowhom(nameIn As Variant)
  hellowhom = "Hello " + CStr(nameIn) + "!"
End Function
```

And doing `=hello()` or `=hellowhom(A1)` in the formula builder.

Any hints or tips??

Comment: What is the value in the cell after you enter `=hello()`? Did you make sure to put the functions in a Module (not the Worksheet/Workbook)?

Comment: The value is #NAME? after entering =hello(). And I have tried to move the functions into a Class module - it does not change anything...

Comment: ohh - just moved it into a MODULE ;o) and now it works!! Thx!!! @Zairja

Comment: I've added my comment as an answer which you may accept to "close" the question. :)

Comment: @ZygD: On these tag edits, generally use a version-agnostic tag ([microsoft-excel] if the issue and solution apply to all versions. Use a version-specific tag when it is unique to a specific version, or include it if you aren't sure. You usually don't need both, or redundant tags like [microsoft-office] when the question is about a specific application like Excel. The [mac] tag is for Mac hardware questions. Use the appropriate OSX tag if it relates to the operating system. Try to include a tag specific to the problem, like [macros] or [vba], in this case.

Answer (score 0):

"The code for a UDF should be placed in a standard code module, not one of the `Sheet` modules and not in the `ThisWorkbook` module. In the VBA editor, go to the *Insert* menu and choose *Module*. This will insert a new code module into the project. A module can contain any number functions, so you can put many functions into a single code module. You can change the name of a module from `Module1` to something more meaningful by pressing the **F4** key to display the *Properties* window and changing the *Name* property to whatever you want."

-from [Chip Pearson's great site](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/writingfunctionsinvba.aspx)